# Changing reference level of binary predictor causes glmer to explode

Tags: r, lme4

Running a glmer (lme4_1.1-10) on a model with a binary DV of score (coded as 1 or 0) and a few binary predictors: Trial Type, which is within-subject (Aff and Neg), and 2 between-subject variables: cdiNo (1 or 0) and cdiNot (1 or 0). Including a random effect with random slope of Trial Type by Subject. Note that here I'm modeling random slope and intercept as uncorrelated. Using bobyqa and maxIter set at 10000. Here's the model:

```
analysis<-glmer(score ~ TrialType*cdiNot + TrialType*cdiNo + (1|UniqueSubject) + (0+TrialType|UniqueSubject)
```

By default, glmer output is dummy coded to make Aff the reference level for TrialType. In that case, the output is perfectly sensible (and theoretically predicted).

```
  AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 1766.8   1819.5   -873.4   1746.8     1431 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3214 -0.8554  0.4693  0.6288  1.5026 

Random effects:
Groups          Name         Variance Std.Dev. Corr
UniqueSubject   (Intercept)  0.3007   0.5484       
UniqueSubject.1 TrialTypeAff 0.2587   0.5087       
             TrialTypeNeg 0.4398   0.6631   0.13
Number of obs: 1441, groups:  UniqueSubject, 183

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)           1.3728     0.5285   2.598  0.00939 **
TrialTypeNeg         -1.1677     0.6652  -1.755  0.07919 . 
cdiNot                0.6915     0.2280   3.033  0.00242 **
cdiNo                -0.4600     0.5394  -0.853  0.39384   
TrialTypeNeg:cdiNot   0.2673     0.2915   0.917  0.35904   
TrialTypeNeg:cdiNo    0.1239     0.6811   0.182  0.85560
```

However, I want to look at the simple effect of cdiNot and cdiNo relative to the other reference level of TrialType. So, I relevel:

```
data$TrialType<-relevel(data$TrialType, ref="Neg")
```

And run the exact same model again. Now I get convergence warnings and an insane output.

```
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 1766.8   1819.5   -873.4   1746.8     1431 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3351 -0.8586  0.4714  0.6301  1.4968 

Random effects:
Groups          Name         Variance Std.Dev. Corr
UniqueSubject   (Intercept)  0.3377   0.5811       
UniqueSubject.1 TrialTypeNeg 0.3917   0.6258       
             TrialTypeAff 0.2263   0.4757   0.02
Number of obs: 1441, groups:  UniqueSubject, 183

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          0.207190   0.001148   180.5   <2e-16 ***
TrialTypeAff         1.149480   0.001148  1001.6   <2e-16 ***
cdiNot               0.949130   0.001147   827.1   <2e-16 ***
cdiNo               -0.330437   0.001148  -287.9   <2e-16 ***
TrialTypeAff:cdiNot -0.247906   0.001147  -216.1   <2e-16 ***
TrialTypeAff:cdiNo  -0.107224   0.001148   -93.4   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) TrlTyA cdiNot cdiNo TrlTypAff:cdNt
TrialTypAff    0.001                                    
cdiNot         0.000  0.000                             
cdiNo          0.000  0.001  0.000                      
TrlTypAff:cdNt 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000               
TrilTypAff:cdN 0.001  0.001  0.000  0.001 0.000         
convergence code: 0
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0624071 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
- Rescale variables?
```

But the mystery deepens. If I just add the correlation of random slope and intercept to the model, the convergence and other warnings disappear, and the output becomes sensible again. So, using Neg as the reference level and running:

```
analysis<-glmer(score ~ TrialType*cdiNot + TrialType*cdiNo + (TrialType|UniqueSubject)
```

The output is:

```
 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
1764.8   1812.2   -873.4   1746.8     1432 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3215 -0.8554  0.4693  0.6288  1.5026 

Random effects:
Groups        Name         Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
UniqueSubject (Intercept)  0.7405   0.8605        
           TrialTypeAff 0.6125   0.7826   -0.59
Number of obs: 1441, groups:  UniqueSubject, 183

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           0.2051     0.5009   0.410   0.6821    
TrialTypeAff          1.1676     0.6654   1.755   0.0793 .  
cdiNot                0.9588     0.2222   4.314  1.6e-05 ***
cdiNo                -0.3360     0.5154  -0.652   0.5144    
TrialTypeAff:cdiNot  -0.2673     0.2915  -0.917   0.3591    
TrialTypeAff:cdiNo   -0.1239     0.6813  -0.182   0.8557    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) TrlTyA cdiNot cdiNo  TrlTypAff:cdNt
TrialTypAff    -0.621                                    
cdiNot         -0.036  0.021                             
cdiNo          -0.966  0.600 -0.121                      
TrlTypAff:cdNt  0.021 -0.021 -0.636  0.078               
TrilTypAff:cdN  0.603 -0.966  0.077 -0.625 -0.120
```

I'm very confused about what might be going on. I suppose I can imagine that if one simple effect is fine and one is unidentifiable, changing the reference level could cause a convergence error (though the astronomical numbers are still unusual). But if I understand correctly, the correlation between random slope and intercept is just an extra parameter for the model to estimate. How could including this parameter make a model that wasn't converging start to?